# awk not printing variables as expected

Tags: variables, awk

Trying really hard to get awk print out the following variables.  But no matter how I tried,

```
awk -F, -v x=$CLIENT_ID -v y=$BRANCH -v z=$UUID -v b=$HERMES_GROUP_CSV_ID 'BEGIN {
    OFS = ","; ORS = "\n"
    } {
        if (length($3) == 0) {
            printf "\nCLIENT $x at $y Linux System Time: $z Pacific Time: $b #####: Column 3, Row "; printf NR; printf " data missing in the Client $x group input csv. Please check\n"
        }
     }' ${INPUT_FILE}
```

it always prints out

```
CLIENT $x at $y Linux System Time: $z Pacific Time: $b #####: Column 3, Row 249 data missing in the Client $x group input csv. Please check
```

Could any guru enlighten?  Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using `$x` as a variable reference, but `$` in awk is to reference fields in the input.  Variables are used without decoration, like `x`.  So:

```
awk -F, -v x=$CLIENT_ID -v y=$BRANCH -v z=$UUID -v b=$HERMES_GROUP_CSV_ID 'BEGIN {
    OFS = ","; ORS = "\n"
    } {
        if (length($3) == 0) {
            print "\nCLIENT "x" at "y" Linux System Time: "z" Pacific Time: "b" #####: Column 3, Row "; printf NR; printf " data missing in the Client "x" group input csv. Please check\n"
        }
    }' ${INPUT_FILE}
```

It looks like `x` is quoted here, but it is not: the point is to have `x` appear NOT in the quoted string, so that it can be expanded as a variable.

Comment: @EdMorton: Good point, but in this case it should be `print` instead of `printf`, since OP is not using format strings actually.  Updated.